# No idea how to read a file in a Docker and spring boot based application

Tags: docker, spring-boot

Facing FileNotFoundException while loading a JSON file which is in /apps/authentication/users.json in docker containers, it is Spring-Boot application. This JSON file is available in /apps/authentication/users.json folder . No idea how to read a file using Docker. Please help.

Trying with below piece of code :

```
    List<User> user = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    TypeReference<List<User>> userMapType = new TypeReference<List<User>>() {};

    InputStream userIs = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("file:///apps/authentication/users.json");
    try {
        user = mapper.readValue(userIs, userMapType);
        log.info("Dummy User Object is created successfully picked from the location : "+dummyUserConfig.getLocation());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        if(null != userIs) {
            try {
                userIs.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

userIs object is null. I already tried lots of combinations of path "file:///apps/authentication/users.json" .

I googled the same and found Docker's volume may be used here. Please guide me

Comment: Just to clarify... the `/apps/authentication/users.json` file is on your host machine, not on the Docker container?

Comment: Please also post all paths you have tried. Also since since it is an external config why are you using `getResourceAsStream` why don't you just read the file using normal File code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `users.json` is on your host machine, but not within your Docker container. You need to use the `-v` parameter (or the `-m` parameter) and either create a separate volume, or use [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/).

This actually mounts a specific folder (or file) on your host machine to a specific folder (or file) on your container, using the following format: `-v SOURCE:DEST`.

In your case, if you only want to share the file, you could use:

```
docker run -v /apps/authentication/users.json:/apps/authentication/users.json your-image
```

If you want to be more permissive and you want to share the entire `/apps` folder, you can use:

```
docker run -v /apps:/apps your-image
```

You don't need to actually change anything in your code. However, if you want to make the location of the file configurable, you can do that by putting it in your `application.properties`:

```
users.file=/apps/authentication/users.json
```

Now you can use `@Value` in your code:

```
@Value("${users.file}")
private FileSystemResource usersFile;
```

Now you can call [`usersFile.getFile()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html#getFile--) or [`usersFile.getInputStream()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html#getInputStream--) and use the same approach you have.

The benefit of doing so is that you can choose where to put your JSON file, and if you want to run it with Docker you can now use the `-e` parameter to pass `USERS_FILE` as an environment variable.

```
docker run -v /apps/authentication/users.json:/custom/folder/users.json -e USERS_FILE /custom/folder/users.json your-image
```

Comment: Thanks for sending the quick response for the same. With this Now I can see the 'apps' folder gets mounted with the container. I Checked with the command : docker exec -it ContainerId  bash ... But execution of this command requires a containerid if a execute ./gradle buildImage .. It creates a container Id . Later on if I execute docker run -v /apps:/apps your-container command now. It creates two instances (docker ps) , one is running on 10.0.0.4 and other one is 172.17.0.4 . My requirement is to have only one instance of my service that too will run on 10.0.0.4. Stuck here badly now..

Comment: With this my 'apps' folder gets mounted with the container. I Checked with the command : 'docker exec -it ContainerId  bash'.Now execution of docker run -v /apps:/apps your-container requires a containerid. So I executed ./gradle buildImage that will create a container Id. Later on if I execute docker run -v /apps:/apps containerid and used the generated containder id to get mounting affects. Now It creates two instances (docker ps), one is running on 10.0.0.4 and other one is 172.17.0.4(Mounted). There shud be only one instance of service that too will run on 10.0.0.4. Stuck here badly now..

Comment: @KapilArora it doesn't require a container ID, you just have to pass your image to it (this **is** the command to run your instance). I've updated my answer to clarify that I meant `your-image` rather than `your-container`

Comment: Huff... I googled about 'docker run' command and found this 'The docker run command first creates a writeable container layer over the specified image, and then starts it using the specified command. That is, docker run is equivalent to the API /containers/create then /containers/(id)/start.' It creates another container means another instance. :-( ... I tried with optional value as  'network = 10.0.0.4' (thought to override existing but in vain) also with 'network = 10.0.0.5' (thought of giving consul's possible new ip but it is in vain too).. it is creating a container on default ip 172...

Comment: Note : I am giving Image ID here not the container Id. I want single instance to be run overall not two.

Comment: @KapilArora Your issue is not clear to me. `docker run` just runs **1** instance, not 2. If you're using the command I gave before, then it will run just 1 instance, which is what you want. I have no idea where the other instance comes from. How do you usually run your container?

Comment: An alternative here is that he could also `COPY` that file while creating the image, so that it is available in the new containers.

Comment: I found the solution as below , did some minor code changes to get the File Object 1st .. check below piece of code and also the same is mounted on the container with ip as 127.0.0.1 :

Comment: <<Code Snippet>>File file = new File("/apps/authentication/users.json");if (file.exists()) {
    user = mapper.readValue(file, userMapType);
   } else {
    InputStream is = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("/user.json");
    user = mapper.readValue(is, userMapType);
   }..... Docker command used :  docker run -d --name=authentication-dummy-service --network=host  --restart unless-stopped -v /apps/authentication:/apps/authentication YOUR-DUMMY-AUTH-SERVICE-IMAGE-ID .. Thanks all for the help and showing me the correct path.

Comment: @KapilArora if you want to be able to change the location easily, put the `/apps/authentication/users.json` in your `application.properties` (eg. call it `users.file=...`). If you use `@Value` and map it to `FileSystemResource`,  you can easily get an inputstream or the file. It also allows you to customize the location with Docker by using the `-e USERS_FILE=...` environment variable.